# Razor - two forms within one html table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

Is it possible to combine these two html tables into one table instead?
I can't seems to do it no matter how, it either tell me no start tag or no close tag for the table.

Goals:

1) One `<table>` with two `<tr>` and each `<tr>` has two `<td>`.

2) Top download button (from top form) in top `<tr>`.

3) Bottom download button (from bottom form) in bottom `<tr>`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateExcelReport", "Pages", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "formExcel", id = "formExcel" }))
            {
                @Html.DevExpress().Button(button =>
                {
                    button.ClientSideEvents.Click = "OnClick";
                    button.Name = "buttonExcel";
                    button.Text = Resources.Global.buttonExportExcelExtra;
                    button.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                }).GetHtml()
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadMainReport", "Pages", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:2px;">
                @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "ExportMode";
                    settings.Properties.Caption = Resources.Global.labelExportMode;// "Details Export Mode ";
                    settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(GridViewDetailExportMode);
                    settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }).BindList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(GridViewDetailExportMode))).Bind(GridViewDetailExportMode.None).GetHtml()
            </td>
            <td style="padding:2px;">
                @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "buttonExportExcel";
                    settings.Text = Resources.Global.buttonExportExcel;
                    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                }).GetHtml()
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.Partial("HomeReportPartial", Model)
}
```

Even if I use div, it will tell me it cannot find matching tag.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("test0", "test0", FormMethod.Post))
            { }
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">3</div>
    </div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("test1", "test1", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

> Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Comment: Do you want to have both `DownloadMainReport` and `GenerateExcelReport` forms support as well?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Your code shows two sets of table tags. There's no reason you shouldn't be able to remove both sets table tags

Comment: of course it's possible in theory. But we don't know exactly what you want instead. Is the issue that you need one "Download" form for each table row (and of course you can't embed a `<form>` tag directly inside a `<tr>`? You might need to put your form tag, combobox and button all inside one `<td>`

Comment: Should you be using tables - this doesn't look like tabular data

Comment: A `<table>` is for tabular data. Do not use tables for layout.

Comment: A better approach is to use "<div>" in this type of layouts